# yo generator stuck - TypeError: Cannot read property 'addListener' of null

Tags: npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yo

I'm trying to create my own simple "Hello World" yeoman generator. 
The very simple one.

I already installed [yeoman generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-generator).

```
npm install -g generator-generator
```

Then I tried to run it.

```
yo generator
```

---

```
     _-----_
    |       |    .--------------------------.
    |--(o)--|    |  Create your own Yeoman  |
   `---------´   |      generator with      |
    ( _´U`_ )    |       superpowers!       |
    /___A___\    '--------------------------'
     |  ~  |     
   __'.___.'__   
 ´   `  |° ´ Y ` 

? Would you mind telling me your username on GitHub? my-name
? What's the base name of your generator? test
```

---

I stuck here almost 10 minutes ....

---

Then, I decide to kill it -  `control` + `c`, I got this.

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.js:579
    throw e;
          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'addListener' of null
    at Function.Observable.fromEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.async.js:426:16)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/inquirer/lib/utils/events.js:9:25)
    at Prompt._run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/confirm.js:60:16)
    at Prompt.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/base.js:71:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/inquirer/lib/ui/prompt.js:96:12)
    at Object.utils.runAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/inquirer/lib/utils/utils.js:29:22)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/inquirer/lib/utils/utils.js:51:13
    at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.js:567:29)
    at setDisposable (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.js:5233:36)
    at AnonymousObservable.s [as _subscribe] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.js:5250:11)
```

---

Some people had same problem : [here](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-generator/issues/113)

Any hints / suggestions ?

Comment: Not sure what's happening, but make sure you're on the latest version of both `yo` and `generator-generator`. Unfortunately, I'm unable to reproduce on node 0.12.

Comment: Also, FWIW the issue you linked on generator-generator is not the same bug you have. They seem unrelated to me.